# What else can i use instead of Number.isInteger?

Tags: javascript

Number.isInteger doesn't work on some IE browsers. I am makin a control wheather value is integer or not.

```
var decimalBasePriceKontol = Number.isInteger(BasePrice);
```

This is my varible.

What else can i use to make work this on all browsers.

Thanks,

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger shows a polyfill you can use ```Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && 
    isFinite(value) && 
    Math.floor(value) === value;
};```

Comment: downvote as the question does not show any research effort. Aside from the solution being listed in the MDN documentation a simple google  `Number.isInteger Internet Explorer` yields immediate results.

Comment: I have fixed it now with polyfill. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You won't get better than the [Mozilla Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger). Add this to the top of your script:

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    return typeof value === 'number' && 
        isFinite(value) && 
        Math.floor(value) === value;
    };
```

Now, what's it doing?

```
// This line makes sure that the function isInteger exists. 
// If it doesn't it creates it
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    // This line checks to make sure we're dealing with a number object.
    // After all "cat" is not an integer
    return typeof value === 'number' && 
    // This line makes sure we're not checking Infinity. 
    // Infinity is a number, and if you round it, then it equals itself.
    // which means it would fail our final test.
    isFinite(value) && 
    // If you round, floor, or ceil an integer, the same value will return.
    // if you round, floor, or ceil a float, then it will return an integer.
    Math.floor(value) === value;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure why anybody would downvote this as its the correct answer? @ChrisG Exactly its in the docs. What are you trying to say?

Comment: I didn't, but this answer is *in the documentation*. The answer encourages skipping the docs and coming here instead.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but probably because the answer is copy pasted from a link, and a link to MDN is probably enough as a comment to close the question. The OP was asking for someone to write code for them.

Comment: @ChrisG Then we could probably delete 80% of Stackoverflow as almost everything is somewhere in the docs.

Comment: @Xatenev Yes, answers that are copies of docs should be deleted. No, it's far less than 80%.

Comment: @Xatenev That's not true, if the answer can be easily found in docs, it doesn't belong here. SO is for code you are trying to work, but can't quite get there, and others will help you fix what you have attempted

Comment: @ChrisG Agree to disagree I suppose.

Comment: @JuanMendes Im pretty sure I can answer 80% of the questions in here with a combination of multiple documentation links. Anyways, agree to disagree I guess.

Comment: @ChrisG I generally try to provide a short, sweet answer, and then fill in with more commentary. A full explanation is now attached.

Comment: I always thought that asking questions on SO is the absolute last thing you want to do, after you have exhausted all other available resources. And the only way to enforce this in order to prevent the site from deteriorating into yahoo answers 2 is to enforce the rules, not feed vampires. Agree to disagree, I suppose. The question shows 0.0 research effort. ZERO.

Comment: @ChrisG Generally, it's my weapon of absolute last resort… but for answering, if I can provide a quality response that leaves the OP a little better than he came here, in general I'd rather fight ignorance. Admittedly, this one is a bit of a gray area… it almost deserves a "WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED???" equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** It works only if the value is number (integer, float, ...). You may check also for other types.

You can convert it to string and then check if there is a `.` character (decimal point).

```
var decimalBasePriceKontol = BasePrice.toString().indexOf(".")==-1
```

You can also make a replacement for Number.isInteger: (run it before the first use of Number.isInteger)

```
if (!Number.isInteger) { // If Number.isInteger is not defined
    Number.isInteger = function (n) {
        return n.toString().indexOf(".")==-1;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if it's an integer, I used the below method in IE browser:

```
if (!value || !/^\d+$/.test(value)) {
    return false;
 } else { 
  //It's an integer
    return true;
}
```